# SQLiteとPHPを用いたSNSで、両思いのユーザーを取得したい

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

SQLiteとPHPを用いたSNSで、メッセージを送れる相手を両思い(お互いがお互いをフォローしている)のユーザーに限りたいのですが、
自分が:idのIDだとして、自分と両思いしているユーザー(ID)一覧を取得するにはどのようなSQL文を発行すればいいのでしょうか?
followテーブルは以下のようになっています。
from_id:フォローしたユーザーID
to_id:フォローされたユーザーID

Answer (score 2):

自分のIDが1だった場合で、followテーブルの中身を以下のように仮定してみます。

```
from_id | to_id
--------+--------
1       | 10
1       | 11
1       | 12
2       | 1
11      | 1
12      | 1
12      | 2
12      | 11
```

この場合、自分がフォローしているユーザーが 10, 11, 12 の3人。また、自分をフォローしているユーザーが 2, 11, 12 の 3人となります。

両思いのユーザーを見つけるには、以下の様にfollowテーブル同士で結合して（一つは自分がフォローしている人のリスト(following)、もう一つは自分をフォローしている人のリスト(follower)）、その following.to_id と follower.from_id、following.from_id と follower.to_id がそれぞれ一致すれば両思いのユーザーとして取得出来るかと思います。

```
SELECT
  following.to_id
FROM follow following
  INNER JOIN follow follower
    ON following.to_id = follower.from_id AND following.from_id = follower.to_id
WHERE following.from_id = :id
```

Answer (score 1):

副問い合わせはどうでしょう？
from_idが１の集合を作り、その中にto_idも１のものとアンドを取るというやりかたです。

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:test.db');
$pdo->query("CREATE TABLE follow(from_id,to_id)");
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO follow VALUES(1,2)");
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO follow VALUES(1,3)");
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO follow VALUES(2,1)");
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO follow VALUES(3,1)");
$pdo->query("INSERT INTO follow VALUES(3,2)");
$sql = "SELECT from_id FROM follow WHERE from_id IN (SELECT to_id FROM follow WHERE from_id=:id) AND to_id=:id";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':id',2,SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$stmt->execute();
while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    var_dump($result);
    echo "<br>";
}
$pdo->query("DROP TABLE follow");
```

Answer (score 1):

これ普通に自己結合すればいいのではないでしょうか。
自己結合もしくは再帰結合で検索すればあまりにも多い結果が出るのでとりあえず参考リンクは貼りません。
質問の具体的なSQLとしては以下になるかと思うのですが、これだと不都合があるのでしょうか。

```
SELECT following.from_id, following.to_id
  FROM follow following, follow followed
    WHERE
      following.to_id = followed.from_id 
    AND
      followed.to_id = following.from_id
  ;
```